# Помогите пожалуйста новичку понять данную часть кода

Tags: java

Только начал изучать Java, помогите пожалуйста понять что обозначает следующая строчка:

```
ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
```

Спасибо за помощь.
Целый код:

```
public class ListNode {
int val;
ListNode next;
ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
}
```

Comment: Это конструктор. По какому учебнику вы изучаете?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

И опять же повторюсь: **уважаемые новички, изучайте классы и ООП полностью, прежде чем писать какие-то примеры и использовать то, чего не знаете**.

Теперь по существу. Непонятное Вам выражение – конструктор класса. По соглашению языка он не должен иметь возвращаемого значения и его имя должно повторять имя класса (что и указывает нам на то, что это именно конструктор).

Конструктор есть метод класса, в теле которого определяются действия, производимые при создании объекта этого класса. В данном случае тело конструктора содержит один оператор: `val = x`, что означает, что свойству `val` вновь созданного объекта будет присвоено значение, переданное в качестве аргумента конструктора.

Например:

```cpp
/* Создаём объект класса ListNode. 
Значение из скобок передаётся в тот самый метод, 
который был Вам непонятен, в качестве аргумента. 
n.val будет равно 5. */

ListNode n(5);
```